# A process serving application pool 'xxx' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service

Tags: c#, iis, crash, application-pool

After a software update the application pool was stopped two times after receiving several errors of this type:
A process serving application pool 'xxx' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was 'yyy'. The data field contains the error number.

Event ID: 5011
Error code: 0x6D000780

Software changes respect to last version was small and can't explain this problem (just a new field in a stored procedure) but I can't restore the old version to check if this have the problem.

I have the same software (the same version) con three servers, one have this issue, the other two no.

After receiving this error several times in each hour this night I tried to restart completely IIS and I didn't receive any error for 5 hours (the application was working also if night time)

The problem appeared again 1 hour after the scheduled recycle time and didn't happen again in the last 4 hours (but I can't consider this problem solved).

What I can do to find the real problem? It's a 100% software problems also if the two nodes are working?

I can increase the "failure interval (minutes)" but this doesn't solve my problem: the software has data in memory and if crash without writing it is a disaster.

I'm using Windows Server 2012 R2 and IIS 8.

Comment: Is there no entry in the event log giving more information about the crash?

Comment: Yes...maybe I have found what generate the problem and why this happens only on one server...should be an unhandled exception that happens only with specific event sequences.

Comment: Could you post more info on what you think you found?  I'm having this same issue on one server.  The app pool restarts randomly with the same Event Log message.  I tried the Debug Diagnostics tool but it's not reporting anything meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

I answer to myself, maybe this could be useful for others in the future.

I believe that in this cause the problem is always a software issue and that the answer can almost always be found in Windows Logs / Application.

Comment: Microsoft has a general troubleshooting guide for years, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/919789/how-to-use-the-debug-diagnostics-tool-to-troubleshoot-an-iis-process-t

Comment: That support link in the comment above is broken. Here is an updated link that works: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-use-the-debug-diagnostics-tool-to-troubleshoot-a-process-that-has-stopped-responding-in-iis-995db9a3-a3be-6d20-cf2f-c48101a64444